# The group $(\Bbb Z_{13}\setminus \{0\}, \cdot)$ is cyclic. Determine all its generators.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups, finitely-generated

> The group $(\Bbb Z_{13}\setminus  \{0\}, \cdot)$ is cyclic. Determine all its generators.

How should I perform to check this by some permutations?

Like $cycle(1) = 2, cycle(2) = 3$ from the set of natural numbers?

Comment: You really want it by permutations or it can be solved by other way?

Comment: @BogaertsMarc that is false. Only $\varphi(12)$ elements of order 12.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I confounded with $\phi(13)$.

Answer (score 1):

Another name for $(\Bbb Z_{13}\setminus \{[0]_{13}\}, \cdot)$ is $U(13)$. It has $\varphi(13)=12$ elements, where $\varphi$ is Euler's totient function.

Note that $U(13)=\langle [2]_{13}\rangle$ is cyclic.

A well-known lemma states that the generators of a cyclic group $\langle a\rangle$ of order $n$ are $a^k$ for $\gcd(k, n)=1$.

Hence the generators are $$\begin{align}
[2]_{13}^1&=[2]_{13}, \\
[2]_{13}^5&=[6]_{13}, \\
[2]_{13}^7&=[11]_{13}, \quad \text{ and}\\
[2]_{13}^{11}&=[7]_{13}.
\end{align}$$